# Define the open set {$O_\alpha$} that covers the $n$-dimensional sphere and the charts $\psi_\alpha:O_\alpha \rightarrow U_\alpha \subset R^n$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, analytic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

That is precisely the question. I thought I would just take n-dimensional spherical coordinates, but somehow that doesn't seem to work. The tasks that build on this make it impossible. Maybe I'm just too stupid. Ultimately, the point is to show that the $n$-dimensional sphere is a manifold. Do you have another possible set $O_\alpha$ with charts $\psi_\alpha$ for me to use?

Comment: Asking for "the" open set seems to imply that it is unique, which is not. Try with the circle $S^1$, you need at least two charts, why?

Comment: Stereographic projection is the usual way. The problem with spherical coordinates it that one chart does not suffice for the whole manifold. You can use combinations of charts of spherical coordinates but that can become complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

1. There is an atlas given by the two stereographic projections $\chi^n_N$ and $\chi^n_S$ from north pole $N = (0,\dots,0,1)$ and south pole $S  = (0,\dots,0,-1)$. Explicitly
   $$\chi^n_N : S^n \setminus \{ N \} \to \mathbb R^n, \chi^n_N((x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})) = \frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}(x_1,\dots,x_n) , $$
   $$\chi^n_S : S^n \setminus \{ S \} \to \mathbb R^n, \chi^n_S((x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})) = \frac{1}{1+x_{n+1}}(x_1,\dots,x_n) . $$
2. There are atlases which are simpler, but have more charts. As an example take the $2(n+1)$ charts living on $U_i^\epsilon = \{ (x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}) \in S^n \mid \epsilon x_i > 0 \}$, with $i = 1,\dots,n+1$ and $\epsilon =\pm 1$, and projecting $U_i^\epsilon$ onto the standard open $n$-ball $B^n = \{ (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 < 1  \}$ by omitting the $i$-th coordinate. Explicitly
   $$\psi_i : U^\epsilon_i \to B^n, \psi_i((x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})) = (x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots, x_{n+1}) .$$

Note that a *single chart cannot form an atlas*: There cannot exist a homeomorphism from $S^n$ to an open $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ because $S^n$ is compact, but no open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact.